# pushing to array element appended with single quote

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

the following varibale is evaluated and adding into array element, getting a single quote when array is printed, how to avoid this,here is the code

```
var t1 = "Date.UTC("+varDate[0]+','+varDate[1]+','+varDate[2]+")"
console.log(t1)
```

The Output is

```
Date.UTC(2001,1,23)
```

then added t1 to an array

```
 diffArray.push(t1)
    console.log(t1)
```

it appended single quote why ? how to avoid this ?

```
[ 'Date.UTC(2001,1,23)']
```

Comment: There is no difference in the internal representation actually. It's just different behavior in outputting a String and an Array.

Comment: That's just the output format used by the console logging mechanism.

Comment: It is still a `Date` object. It is just displayed as a string when using console.log.

Comment: @KJPrice no, it's not. It's a string. At no point in the code shown here is that a date object.

Comment: @KJPrice It is at no point a date object. He never evaluates the string he generates! If he wants to have a `Date` object, he should not try to build it as a string.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I misread. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just `console.log()` showing you that the item in the array is a string.  Your `t1` variable has always been a string so there is no difference in the internal representation, just how `console.log()` chooses to display it.

If you do `console.log(diffArray[0])`, you will see the original representation without quotes just because that's what `console.log()` does when you give it a plain string.  When you give `console.log()` an array, it puts quotes around any elements that are strings to indicate the difference between a string and some other type that the array might hold.

Look in your console for this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yrannpm2/

```
console.log(t1);             // Date.UTC(2001,1,23)
console.log(diffArray[0]);   // Date.UTC(2001,1,23)
console.log(diffArray);      // ["Date.UTC(2001,1,23)"]
```